# Error (single-row subquery returns more than one row)

Tags: sql, oracle

What is wrong with this query?

```
select en.*,
       (select sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow from data2 sf )
from data1 en;
```

I have error

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: What you didn't understand here? the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Skip the sub-query, do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: use TOP 1:
select en.*,
       (select TOP 1sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow from data2 sf )
from data1 en;

Comment: @MRsa - The question is tagged `[oracle]`. TOP is not valid syntax in Oracle

Comment: How many rows do you see when you run the subquery `select sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow from data2 sf` on its own? What is the relationship between `data` and `data2` - you may have just forgotten to include correlation in the subquery; but a join is almost certainly more appropriate anyway, even if you expect exactly one `data2` row to match each `data1` row. (And if it is a strictly 1-to-1 relationship, why have two tables at all?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select en.*,
       (select sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow from data2 sf )
from data1 en;
```

A subquery in the `select` used like this is called a *scalar subquery*.  Such a subquery can be used where a scalar value (i.e. single value such as a number or string) can be used.

Scalar subqueries must meet two conditions:

- It returns at most one row.
- It returns one column.

The solution in your case is simple, using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select en.*, sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow 
from data1 en left join
     data2 sf
     on 1=1;
```

Or, in Oracle 12C, you can use a lateral join:

```
select en.*, sf.red, sf.blue, sf.green, sf.yellow 
from data1 en left join lateral
     data2 sf
     on 1=1;
```

The two look the same in this case, but a lateral join can also be used for a correlated subquery.

Comment: Can you expand on what the ```lateral``` join achieves in a different example, where the query is different compared to a standard ```left join```?